# Calculate deltas between items in a list

Tags: clojure, lisp

If I have a list of values, what is an effective way to calculate the difference between the elements in the list?

For example:
`'(5 10 12 15)` would result in `'(5 2 3)`, or `'(0 5 2 3)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do this also:

```clj
(def xs '(5 10 12 15))

(map - (rest xs) xs)
;; => (5 2 3)
```

`map` applies the function `-` to two lists:

```
  10  12  15
-  5  10  12  15
----------------
   5   2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need `partition` for this, then a regular `mapv` (or `map`):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.string :as ts] ))

(dotest
  (let [data   [5 10 12 15]
        pairs  (partition 2 1 data)
        deltas (mapv (fn [[x y]] ; destructure pair into x & y
                       (- y x))  ; calculate delta
                 pairs)]
    (is= pairs [[5 10] [10 12] [12 15]])
    (is= deltas [5 2 3])))
```

Be sure to see [the Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) for fast reference to functions like this (read it every day!).

Comment: appreciate the example for partition, as well as the cheat sheet, thank you!